# Brownian motion on the circle

Tags: stochastic-processes, potential-theory

Let $\mathbb S^1$ be the unit circle and $\Delta$ be the [Laplace-Beltrami operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) on $\mathbb S^1$ which is an infinitesimal generator of the correspondent Markov semigroup $P_t$. Is the explicit distribution of this Markov process known?

Comment: You should check http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/28/6/643.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brownian motion on the circle can be written as $X_t = e^{i B_t}$ where $B_t$ is a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the journal of applied functional analysis vol7, page 26 . 
The article is the random motion on the sphere generated by the Laplace Beltrami Operator. The authors are V.G.Papanicolaou and D. Kouloumpou.
Is my phd work